# How to fix Incorrect Syntax near returns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying find fetch employee grade from employee table and set the value 
based on grade and return an integer value,but I get error in second line as incorrect syntax near returns
I am trying to learn sql server

```
 create procedure checkgrade(@empid int)
    returns int
    as 
    begin
        declare @cgrade char(1)
        declare @rint int
            select @cgrade=grade from employee where @empid=empid
            if @cgrade='M' set @rint =1
            else if  @cgrade='L' set @rint=2
            else if @cgrade='T' set @rint=3
            else if @cgrade='X' set @rint= 4
            else set @rint=0
        return @rint
    end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used syntax of function in procedure.

```
create Function checkgrade(@empid int)
returns int
as 
begin
    declare @cgrade char(1)
    declare @rint int
        select @cgrade=grade from employee where @empid=empid
        if @cgrade='M' set @rint =1
        else if  @cgrade='L' set @rint=2
        else if @cgrade='T' set @rint=3
        else if @cgrade='X' set @rint= 4
        else set @rint=0

    return @rint
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Function` instead of `Procedure`.

```
create Function checkgrade(@empid int)
    returns int
    as 
    begin
        declare @cgrade char(1)
        declare @rint int
            select @cgrade=grade from employee where @empid=empid
            if @cgrade='M' set @rint =1
            else if  @cgrade='L' set @rint=2
            else if @cgrade='T' set @rint=3
            else if @cgrade='X' set @rint= 4
            else set @rint=0
        return @rint
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `output` parameter to Output the result

```
create procedure checkgrade @empid int, @rint int OUTPUT   
    as 
    begin
        declare @cgrade char(1)

            select @cgrade=grade from employee where @empid=empid
            if @cgrade='M' set @rint =1
            else if  @cgrade='L' set @rint=2
            else if @cgrade='T' set @rint=3
            else if @cgrade='X' set @rint= 4
            else set @rint=0       
    end
```

Comment: i wanted to use function instead of procedure

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE has slightly different syntax:

```
 create procedure checkgrade(@empid int)
    as
    begin
        declare @cgrade char(1)
        declare @rint int
            select @cgrade=grade from employee where @empid=empid
            if @cgrade='M' set @rint =1
            else if  @cgrade='L' set @rint=2
            else if @cgrade='T' set @rint=3
            else if @cgrade='X' set @rint= 4
            else set @rint=0
        return @rint
    end;
```

In fact, it can be that you need function instead of procedure as other members suggested